# disable Celery ForkPoolWorker logs

Tags: logging, scrapy, celery

I'm new in **Celery**. 
I want to disable worker logs on Celery Screen. So, I run celery like this.

[image]

But after I send task Celery Server...

[image]

Still output worker logs

I tried `get_task_logger` but not working

Comment: Found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least limit the log level to `FATAL`:

```
 celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=FATAL
```

If you don't want to see the logs you can also send the output of the process somewhere else:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=FATAL &>/dev/null
```